# Thunderbird + Lightning using Google Calendar

Tags: thunderbird, gmail, calendar, lightning

I'm currently struggling to get my Google calendar integrated in Thunderbird with Lightning. 
I'm not using the Google Calendar Plugin instead I use the WebDav URL from google:

```
https://apidata.googleusercontent.com/caldav/v2/myemail@gmail.com/events
```

But then I only get my own calendar and not the calendars that are shared with my ( I have read/write access to). Does anyone have a idea what I have to do?

Comment: Can you get DAV link for shared calendars?

Comment: Why don't you set the page as homepage in Thunderbird? That way, every time you open it, it'll show an active calendar. I used to change the homepage to other webpages I visited often, and this part of the UI (the reading pane, as it is), is just a regular browser windows, characteristics-wise, on the same model as Firefox.

Comment: "window", singular.

Comment: @p0rc0_r0ss0 That was a good hint. I can get a calendar-id in the settings of the calendars and then with this id add another calender. But tthis sadly is only a part time solution. The birthdays of my contacts for example I still can't see. And I can't get a calendar-id for that.

Comment: @Didier this would be a workaround but so I can't accept invitations that I get my mail and also I don't think that i get reminders using this way.

Comment: I don't use Google Calendar, so I couldn't say, but if you don't want to, or can't, use the plugin, then a workaround is better than nothing. Have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have to add each of the calendars that are shared with you separately:

Following the [instructions on the google website](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37648?hl=en#zippy=%2Csync-your-google-calendar-view-edit%2Cget-your-calendar-view-only) you can find the "Secret address in iCal format" (Refer to the section on "Get your calendar (view only)"). For me the URL was actually labelled "Public address in iCal format", probably that's how it's called in cases where you only have read access to a calendar.

Once you have this URL, you can add it to Thunderbird:

- In Thunderbird, go to File -> New -> Calendar
- Choose "On the network"
- Leave the username empty. As a location, enter the URL you found in the previous step. Tick the box "This location doesn't require credentials".
- Hit "Find calendars" and you should be able to see the correct calendar (for me it was named with a default name "basic", but it had the correct information)